# Принцип работы Dp (Density-independent pixels)

Tags: android, android-studio, design, density

Dp (density-independent pixel) равен размеру одного физического пикселя на экране с плотностью пикселей 160 ppi. То есть экран размером по высоте 1 дюйм, и имеющий 160 пикселей по высоте, будет иметь 160 ppi по высоте и следовательно 160 dp на дюйм. Экран размером по высоте 2 дюйма, и имеющий 320 пикселей по высоте, будет иметь также 160 ppi по высоте и следовательно 160 dp на дюйм. Теперь вопрос: если я рисую кнопку размером 16 dp на 16 dp на первом экране, она будет занимать по высоте 10 процентов, как будет отрисована эта кнопка на втором экране, сохраняться ли пропорции (10 процентов по высоте от высоты) и т.д.?
Если же процентное соотношение будет нарушено, то как тогда в андроиде следят за тем чтобы поддерживать одинаковые пропорции экрана?

Comment: Не будет. Используйте как вариант "веса".

Comment: Тут вопрос не столько в том что надо использовать, сколько в том, как работает этот dp и в чем его назначение. Пока что все что я нашел это что dp нужен чтобы нивелировать плотность экрана и обеспечить одинаковое физическое отображение элемента, при этом физические размеры экрана не учитываются, учитывается только плотность.

Comment: На экране размером по высоте 1 дюйм и 320 пикселей по высоте будут соблюдены пропорции (10%). Экран размером по высоте 2 дюйма и 320 пикселей по высоте это просто два экрана размером по высоте 1 дюйм и 160 пикселей по высоте. На нем кнопка будет абсолютно такой же (плотность не изменилась), соответственно станет 5% по высоте просто потому что экран в 2 раза больше.

Comment: Поэтому и принято смотреть на размеры экрана в DP, тогда такие вопросы не возникают. Экран в 1 дюйм и 320 пикселей по высоте -- это 160dp, а 2 дюйма и 320 пикселей -- это 320dp.

Comment: Принцип работы очень простой: на любом экране `1 dp ≈ 1/160 in`, то есть одинаковый **физический** размер, а не относительно параметров экрана. Когда это может быть полезно? Например. для удобства пользования кнопками, они должны быть не меньше подушечки пальца - это физическая величина. Или толщину разделительной линии, обводки лучше указать в `dp`, так как в пикселях она будет видна на экране с низкой плотностью, но не различима на 8К

Comment: Хорошо, это я понял. Какие инструменты используются в андроиде чтобы интерфейс нарисованный на экране 160 dp, был пропорционально такой же на экране высотой 320 dp, чтобы кнопка если занимает на 160 dp 10 % от экрана, занимала столько же процентов и на экране в 320 dp, в данном случае по высоте?

Comment: Используют контейнеры (`XxxLayout`), у каждого свои возможности по расположению элементов и распределеию пространства между ними. Например: `LinearLayout` предоставляет свойство "вес" (weight) - задаёте кнопке вес `10`, остальным элементам распределяете `90` (вот вам в сумме 100%). Есть контейнеры, поддерживающие размеры в процентах (не помню какие, что-то из JetPack, он же AndroidX)

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду знать. Завис сегодня с этими размерами, пропорциями и т.д., но уже более менее что хотел понять, понял. Можете ответ написать, отмечу как правильный, чтобы вопрос не висел.